# GlideImage composable in Landscapist library missing some parameters

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-image

The [`GlideImage`](https://github.com/skydoves/landscapist#glideimage) composable in the [`Landscapist`](https://github.com/skydoves/landscapist) image loading library for Compose is missing the [`loading`, `success`, and `failure`](https://github.com/skydoves/landscapist#custom-composables) parameters, but the GitHub Readme for the library states these parameters are available. Android Studio just throws a compile time error. Do I have to implement them differently with this library?

```
GlideImage(
  imageModel = imageUrl,
  modifier = modifier,
  // Throws compiler error here
  loading = {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()) {
      CircularProgressIndicator(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
      )
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I try replicate but works for me. I using version 1.4.9 of Glide. You can try implement success and failure too.

```
GlideImage(
     modifier = Modifier
         .size(40.dp)
         .background(Color.Green),
     imageModel = "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AMLnZu-v-ApUfdP0KinqrJQyNYP5BVd1ke0C7HsoTtkH=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      success = {
         Image(
              painter = rememberDrawablePainter(drawable = it.drawable),
              contentDescription = null
         )
      },
      failure = {
         Image(
             painter = rememberDrawablePainter(drawable = it.errorDrawable),
             contentDescription = null
         )
      },
      loading = {
         Box(modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()) {
             CircularProgressIndicator(
                  modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                  progress = it.progress
             )
       }
   }
)
```

Comment: `Glide` version 1.4.9 is an older version, the latest version which the the `Landscapist` library is using internally is 4.13.2. I want to use the latest version though, and it seems like these parameters aren't included in the latest version.

Comment: @rajndev, can you show the error? Will be very helpful. Because I update the Glide to last version (1.5.2) and still works in my project.

Comment: The error says `Unresolved reference: loading`, and 1.5.2 is not the last version. The last version is 4.13.2 as stated in the library's Github repo page @ https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases/tag/v4.13.2. Can you show me which dependency you are using in the Gradle file? Thanks.

Comment: My glide dependency is "com.github.skydoves:landscapist-glide:1.5.2". I just remember now. Is a library that use Glide, Fresco e Coil to be a easy implementation with Compose. Here is the link https://github.com/skydoves/landscapist

Comment: I'm using the latest version 1.5.3. I think they removed those parameters in version 1.5.3.